# Generate required output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in first format given below. I want the output in second format. Help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
UserID  IsManagerFeedback   Level
---------------------------------
User 1  FALSE                2
User 2  FALSE                3
User 5  FALSE                2
User 1  TRUE                 4
User 3  TRUE                 1
User 4  TRUE                 3
User 5  TRUE                 5




UserID  UserFeedback    ManagerFeedback
---------------------------------------
User 1  2               4
User 2  3               NA
User 3  NA              1
User 4  NA              3
User 5  2               5
```

Comment: Sorry for the format as i have a very old browser in the machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
UserID,
MAX(CASE WHEN IsManagerFeedback = 'FALSE' THEN Level END) AS UserFeedback,
MAX(CASE WHEN IsManagerFeedback = 'TRUE' THEN Level END) AS ManagerFeedback
FROM
Table1
GROUP BY UserID
```

See it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4252/2/0).

UPDATE:

```
SELECT
Year,
UserID,
MAX(CASE WHEN IsManagerFeedback = 'FALSE' THEN Level END) AS UserFeedback,
MAX(CASE WHEN IsManagerFeedback = 'TRUE' THEN Level END) AS ManagerFeedback
FROM
Table1
GROUP BY Year, UserID
```

Comment: What can be the solution if i have another column with year as well which i need to show?

Comment: Sorry, not getting the desired result. i'd rather post it as a separate question as the concept is a bit different